# Eclipse problem keeps opening old versions/copies of the files

Tags: php, windows, eclipse

I am having problem with my Eclipse PDT version. I keeps opening older version of a file until I close it and open it again.

So what is happening. I edit a file with Eclipse - test.php. I close it. Then I compare it (test.ph) with another one in WinMerge, save the changes and when I open the file again in Eclipse it is still the same as it was before I changed it in WinMerge. I have to close the Eclipse and start it again to be able to open the file with it latest modifications.

I have noticed the same problem when I am opening a file downloaded from FileZilla. I have a local copy of the file that is online opened in Eclipse, then someone changed the file online. I right click -> "View/edit" from FileZilla, choosing to overide the old local file with the one online, but then I see the old file again, without the changes. I am sure that there are changes cause when I downlaod the file somewhere and open it , I see them.

Is there something like a cache in the Eclipse that may prevents me from viewing the latest changes. I seems that is happens only when the changes were made outside/not usign Eclipse. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any way to open a file outside the project without it being cached and to be able to reopen it and see the actual code?

This is a huge disadvantage of the Eclipse. I do not know how things like this could be left the way they are?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Eclipse likes caching a lot... one of the reasons I hate it.

You should be able to have Eclipse auto-refresh your files in the *Preferences* window in the *Window* menu (type `Refresh` to show up the relevant pages). In my not so recent version of Eclipse, I have to put checkmarks on these:

- *Refresh workspace on startup* (in *Startup and Shutdown*)
- *Refresh automatically* (in *Workspace*)

Comment: Could this also be the reason for this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577010/possible-problem-in-eclipse-usage-with-svn

Comment: I also noticed that this happens with files that are not part of any project - they are not part of my workspace. I still find it annoying!!! It also happens with file from my working space when I do not open them from the PHP explorer in Eclipse but directly from the Windows Explorer, which is also strange.

Comment: In my case, it was MyEclipse and it wasted my entire afternoon. Thanks Archimedix this worked.

Answer (score -1):

The answer given by Archimedix solved a similar problem (in Java) that I have where the config files (hbm config and log4j) that I have modified in the eclipse editor are not being copied to the output folder. Instead an older version of the file is being copied every time I compile. I followed Archemedix solution, however, note that you still need to restart eclipse for it to take effect. After restarting eclipse, during compilation, any changes I make to the config files are now being copied to the output folder and not the old version.